# How to fix "_COMPlusExceptionCode = -532459699"?

Tags: exception, com

Getting "_COMPlusExceptionCode = -532459699" Exception when tried call COM component method(SaveOnline)..
ADODB.Recordset SavedCreditCard1 = ObjboCreditCard.SaveOnline(sUID, rsCardData, true, false, false, false);

I did some research and come to know that,this exception occures when we tried to insert null into not nullable field.
Method from COM component accepts record set(rsCardData) as parameter and there is one integer field in record set having null value(as default value) but when i tried to assign some value to it,its giving another exception as "Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value."
Please help me to fix this problem.
Thanks..

Comment: The error code is 0xe0434f4d, that's the exception code for a managed exception.  You'll need to use a debugger to find out what unhandled exception is getting thrown.  Debug + Exception, tick Thrown box to make the debugger stop when the exception is raised.